# Why nicEdit WYSIWYG editor sometimes prevent sending value exactly?

Tags: php, load, return-value, send, nicedit

I have used nicEditor on an administration control panel in my project. But there is something strange.
When I want to send a value to insert into database, it works well. But in an edit page, when I want to process the sent value from textarea, only the first value inserted in textarea will be sent and if I want to change this value, in the next page I have the first value again.
This is the code I have used to convert all textareas to nicEditor.

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
```

Now imagine that I have a form that consists stored value in database like this:

```
<textarea name="description"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
```

If `$description` value be **123**, and I change it to **1234** and then submit the form, given sent value from `$_POST['description']` is **123** that is incorrect. But when I remove the first line that loads nicEditor, the sent value changes to **1234** that is correct.

What's the problem?

**Edits:**
This is I have in the first page:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_hotels WHERE id = ?";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
$result = $q->fetch();
$des = $r['des'];
?>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
  <textarea name="des" class="large-input"><?php echo $des; ?></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

And this is what I did in next page:

```
<?php
$des = $_POST['des'];
echo $des;
?>
```

Comment: Please write your reason for your vote to close. Do you have any useful solution?

Comment: Are you saying that you're literally writing "`<textarea name="description"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>`" in a text area, which is then apparently `eval`d on the server?

Comment: Yes. This is the code I always used without any problem. Here `$description` is taken from database.

Comment: Even if I put a simple value between textarea tags, the manner is the same.

Comment: Nobody have not any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Taken directly from their site http://nicedit.com/docs.php

> Nicedit is no longer under active development, you might want to try
>   CKEditor or TinyMCE instead.

That being said your most likely submitting your form in some other manner then a normal submit so the editor is not syncing with your `<textarea>` you could try firing the below code to sync before submit.

`[nicInstance].saveContent()`

- Only for nicInstances that are replacing a  this method syncs the content of the editor with the textarea value. This is done automatically if the form with the orginal  is submitted. However, you may want to explitly do the syncing yourself.

Edit:

JS

```
var myform = document.getElementById('myForm');
myform.addEventListener('submit', function() { 
    var myEditor = nicEditors.findEditor('myEditor');
    myEditor.saveContent(); 
    return true;
});
```

PHP

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="myForm">
  <textarea name="des" class="large-input" id="myEditor"><?php echo $des; ?></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: I had not this problem before. In my current project it works well in most of cases. But there are 2 pages with the mentioned problem.

Comment: @MohammadBagherSaberi please include the complete code for those 2 pages what you have provided is not enough to go on.

Comment: there are hundreds lines of code. I provided what you think is important. It is so simple, and I think it has not any unknown point

Comment: @MohammadBagherSaberi I have made an edit to my answer above with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Because niceEditor  operation is different. When you add niceEditor to your textarea.

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
```

The niceEditor hide all your textareas and which add new **contenteditable** div instead of textareas. When you are enter any text like  **123** that niceEditor take it as html format that is `<span>&nsub123</span>`. When you are try to bold your text `<span style='bold'>123</span>`. In your problem when you enter 123 that niceEditor add hidden space `&nsub;` with your enterd text that is like `&nsub;123`. So when you POST this text you must convert text by **`htmlentities()`** AND **`mysql_real_escape_string()`** . Also when time of retrieve these text from DB you must decode these text by **`html_entity_decode()`** function.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_hotels WHERE id = ?";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
$result = $q->fetch();
$des = html_entity_decode($r['des']);
?>
```

And

```
<?php
   $des = htmlentities($_POST['des']);
   echo $des;
?>
```

Comment: `htmlentities()` could not solve my problem. By the way, I told I had not this problem before. In the current project, I have this problem only in 2 cases and other cases work correctly without needing to any other code.